# How to determine which data set is more accurately modeled with a linear function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this word problem that I'm not sure how to solve it. I'm wondering what to do to find out which data set is more accurately modeled with a linear function? The question says

> Data set A has a correlation of 0.8, and data set B has a correlation of -0.9. Which set of data is more accurately modeled with a linear function? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlation coefficients are used to measure the strength of the linear relationship between two variables.

A correlation coefficient value which **greater than zero indicates a positive relationship** while a correlation coefficient value which **less than zero signifies a negative relationship**. A value of **zero** indicates **no relationship between the two variables being compared**.

A positive correlation is when both variables move in the same direction. A negative correlation is when both variables move in the opposite direction.

According to the rule of correlation coefficients, the strongest correlation is considered when the value is closest to +1 (positive correlation) or -1 (negative correlation). A positive correlation coefficient indicates that the value of one variable depends on the other variable directly.

So, by means, **Data B has strongest correlation (-0.9 -> -1.0 has 0.1 gap)** comparing to Data A (0.8 -> 1.0 has 0.2 gap)